# Trivial: Get confirmation of email sent in android

Tags: java, android, email, android-intent

After starting an email intent how can I get confirmation that the email has sent or there has been an error back into the activity it was called from?

```
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("png/image");

        String subject = "Email Subject";

        String body = "Message Body"; 

        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/" + IMAGE_FILENAME));

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email...")); 

        //Here I need to do something on a successfully sent email
```

Maybe start activityForResult? But what result should I expect back if any?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That really depends on the app that is launched by your `Intent`. It could be the Gmail app, it could be the Email app, or it could be any third-party app. Because of this, there is no 100% reliable way to determine whether the user actually pressed <kbd>Send</kbd> or not.

The only thing you can do is check if the Gmail and Email apps return anything relevant when called via `startActivityForResult` and rely on that. But beware that is not reliable because, again, there could be third party apps. Also, since these apps do not specify publicly what they return, they might change that at some point without any notice.

Comment: Looks like there is no way of getting a resultCode back then, thanks for your help.

Comment: The Gmail app returns RESULT_OK for resultCode also when you press cancel :/

Answer (score 3):

you cannot get any useful resultcode from an email intent. onActivityResult always return 0 as soon as sending starts or sending is canceled.

Additionaly if you attach files, onActivityResult is called BEFORE those files are read.

Answer (score 2):

You can NOT do this.

ACTION_SEND does NOT have any output as a result you always get the default value which is RESULT_CANCELED.

Also you can NOT check it with Intent data coming back because it is always null either mail send or discard.