# Issue with email intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have developed an application in android in which I am supposed to send an email from this application using Intent. I am able to send the email, but I am not sure that the email has been sent- because I do not have an option to know the acknowledgement for the email sent.

Please find me a solution to to confirm that the email has been sent in some sort of alert.

code :

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); email.setType("plain/text");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {emailId});
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Documents"); email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Please find attachment");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(myFile)); 
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email , "Send email..."));
```

Comment: post you  intent code here

Comment: Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
            email.setType("plain/text");
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {emailId});
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Documents");
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Please find attachment");
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(myFile));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email , "Send email..."));

Answer (score 0):

Check these two answers: [Trivial: Get confirmation of email sent in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471217/trivial-get-confirmation-of-email-sent-in-android) and [Android e-mail sending verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976329/android-e-mail-sending-verification?lq=1). They talk about the same problem that you want to solve. Hope it helps.