# Android - Get a Response of Sent Email

Tags: android, email

I am working on a live app. I am allocating a specific points to the user as he/she shares our text via email. But, how can I recognize that user has sent an email??

I am using following **code**,

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{});                 
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey there! Please download the fun app");
email.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Select Email Chooser"));
```

How can I get the response that user has sent an Email?

Comment: Kinda related, to only get email clients, do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-can-i-send-emails-from-my-android-application/41944560#41944560

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this cannot be done. Since any application can respond to the Intent there is no guarantee of any result code or result intent.

See:

[Get Mail Sent Notification in onActivityResult "Android"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600149/get-mail-sent-notification-in-onactivityresult-android)

See:

[Trivial: Get confirmation of email sent in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471217/trivial-get-confirmation-of-email-sent-in-android)

My own personal tests on ICS are showing both email clients returning 0 for the resultCode regardless of whether the user presses back or send.

Comment: My app is also 4.0 and above. I tried `asyntask` also, but no exact solution. :(

Comment: @Mitesh also you can write custom mail server, and use json queries))